# Get version from a file for release job in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've a custom `pyproject.toml` based python package, where I get the version of the package dynamically using `version = {attr = "my_package.VERSION"}` (read from `my_package/src/version.py`).I want to set up a release job in CI so that I can make new releases every time, along with version information read from the same file.

Following a couple of related questions, I tried the following, where `registry_upload` is the step which builds and uploads the wheel file into the package registry with `twine`:

```yaml
release_version:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - artifacts: false
      job: registry_upload
  release:
    description: release of version ${VERSION_NUMBER} of my_package
    ref: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
    tag_name: v${VERSION_NUMBER}
  script:
    - VERSION_NUMBER=$(grep -E -o "[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?" ${CI_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/my_package/src/version.py)
    - echo ${VERSION_NUMBER}
```

This does create a release, but the `VERSION_NUMBER` variable in unavailable to release steps apparently, leading to tag being `v` instead of `v0.0.1` (for example) and similarly for description. I can edit the description manually later, but not the tag, so it'd definitely cause issues during next release.

I want to know how to make the variable exposed to tag/description/etc. fields. It's getting defined successfully as I could `echo` it in `scripts` section and verify, but just not getting passed on.

Comment: Previously asked at https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-release-get-version-from-a-file/75548?u=anirban.ray

Comment: It looks like there's an export missing in the script:

replace `VERSION_NUMBER=$(grep -E -o "[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?" ${CI_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/my_package/src/version.py)`

to

`export VERSION_NUMBER=$(grep -E -o "[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?" ${CI_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/my_package/src/version.py)`

does it work that way ?

Comment: Since `echo` worked, I don't think it matters here. But I tried nevertheless, and that led to same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitlab docmentation explicitly tells us that the variables defined in `script` or `before_script` are not available for other aspects of the job.

```yaml
      release:
        description: release of version ${VERSION_NUMBER} of my_package
        ref: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
        tag_name: v${VERSION_NUMBER}
```

The `VERSION_NUMBER` is not defined as the `script`: (and unfortunately also `before_script`) are executed AFTER the evaluation of the `release.tag_name` value. There is no way around this, except using dynamic variables:

```yaml
     variables:
       VERSION_NUMBER: $(grep -E -o "[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?\.[0-9]+?" ${CI_PROJECT_DIRECTORY}/my_package/src/version.py))
     release:
       description: release of version ${VERSION_NUMBER} of my_package
       ref: ${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}
       tag_name: v${VERSION_NUMBER}
```

Comment: I was not aware that `variables` support `grep` or other evaluations. Thanks.